# Will someone please explain RESULT_FIRST_USER

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I don't understand the meaning, value, or importance of RESULT_FIRST_USER, other than that my own result codes must be greater than `1`. Will someone please explain it? RESULT_OK and RESULT_CANCELED make perfect sense to an english speaker. But what in the world of android is RESULT_FIRST_USER? All the documentations says about it is

```
Start of user-defined activity results.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you finish an activity, you can call `setResult(RESULT_CODE)` to send back data to another activity. If you don't call this method, the default value will be `RESULT_CANCELLED` (which equals `0`)

Example of returning data:

```
Intent intent= new Intent();
intent.putExtra("data",data);
setResult(YOUR_RESULT_CODE,intent);
finish();
```

Comment: Then why didn't they just call it RESULT_EMPTY or something similar? Why in the world FIRST_USER? The name makes it sound like there is more to the story. Does FIRST_USER mean something in the android ecosystem or in software engineering that I am not aware of? I am thankful for your reply, of course. But the name is suspicious, don't you think?

Comment: My guess is that they added it so you know when to start your custom values, as `RESULT_OK` is -1 and `RESULT_CANCELED` is 0

Comment: @KatedralPillon: "Why in the world FIRST_USER?" -- it's a fairly common convention in managing integer return codes, in cases where multiple parties (e.g., a library author and an app author) might want to define those codes. I remember seeing this in use in C/C++ 20-25 years ago. Basically, any values lower than `RESULT_FIRST_USER` are reserved for the framework, and any values starting with `RESULT_FIRST_USER` are up for apps to use, without risk of collision. You don't see it much in Android, at least at the Java level.

Comment: I thought if you finish an activity without calling setResult, RESULT_CANCELED will be received?

Comment: I just tested this and you're right, correcting my answer

Comment: @AndrewBrooke I think it would be a good idea to edit your answer and include CommonsWare comment as additional information so everyone else can see it easily.

Comment: RESULT_FIRST_USER is supposed to be used by your app to start defining codes, like this:
class MyActivity extends Activity {
    public static final int RESULT_THING1_FAILED = RESULT_FIRST_USER + 1;
    public static final int RESULT_THING2_FAILED = RESULT_FIRST_USER + 2;
...
}

That way if they ever reserve more codes, your code won't break.

Comment: Please Andrew, use @KatedralPillon comment to complete your answer, because the question points to the autor knowing what you just said but the real part is missing. With KatedralPillon's comment the answer will be perfect. Look for Avid's answer too.

Comment: The documentation also provides some insight as to why it's called that:
`Start of user-defined activity results.`
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#RESULT_FIRST_USER

Comment: This answer's comments answer the question, but the actual answer does not.

Answer (score 34):

The answer to the question is actually the combination of comments from @CommonsWare and @Chris. So, for the sake of progeny, I am going to consolidate the comments and make it available in one place.

Basically, there are two predefined constants for the `requestCode` and they are `Activity.RESULT_OK` and `Activity.RESULT_CANCELLED`. However, android developers can also set custom codes for their apps by using the offset `Activity.RESULT_FIRST_USER`. Doing so ensures that there are no clashes between constants set at the OS level and the app level.

Purely, my opinion, I think that the `FIRST USER` suffix is meant to refer to developers – just like how end consumer refers to consumers of a said product – who are the first users before the app users.

Below is an example of how you can use this offset,

```
public static final int MY_RESULT_CODE = Activity.RESULT_FIRST_USER + 1;
```

Comment: This really should be the accepted answer, because it actually answers the question. The code example makes it even clearer.

Comment: Update the requestCode with resultCode

Answer (score 14):

When an activity ends, it can call `setResult(int)` to return data back to its parent.

It **must** always supply a result code, which can be the standard results

- `RESULT_CANCELED` (Standard activity result: Operation canceled. Constant Value: 0)
- `RESULT_OK` (Standard activity result: operation succeeded. Constant Value: -1), or any custom values starting at `RESULT_FIRST_USER` (Start of user-defined activity results. Constant Value: 1). In addition, it can optionally return back an Intent containing any additional data it wants.

So, bottom line since you must supply the result code Android "helps' you a bit by saying: *please state if the result code of this Activity is **OK***, **CANCELED** or you have your own, custom made, result.

Answer (score 2):

An activity result is a 32-bit integer. The possible values are divided into three ranges:

- **-2 and below:** Unused.
- **-1 and 0:** System-defined values. That is, activity results defined by Android.
- **1 and above**: User-defined values. That is, activity results defined by app developers.

`RESULT_FIRST_USER` identifies the first value in the user-defined range. The following sample definitions show how system- and user-defined values fit together:

```java
public static final int RESULT_OK = -1; // Defined by Android. You don't write this code.
public static final int RESULT_CANCELED = 0; // Defined by Android. You don't write this code.
public static final int RESULT_ENDED_GAME = RESULT_FIRST_USER + 0; // Defined by an app.
public static final int RESULT_ACTIVATED_RADAR = RESULT_FIRST_USER + 1; // Defined by an app.
public static final int RESULT_LAUNCHED_ROCKETS = RESULT_FIRST_USER + 2; // Defined by an app.
```