# Android, In App Billing, getBuyIntent(), Activity.RESULT_OK, v3

Tags: android, response, in-app-billing, onactivityresult

I am currently [implementing inAppBilling](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html) (v3) into my application and came across a little problem. I purchase an item with the code from the guideline:

```
Bundle buyIntentBundle = mService.getBuyIntent(3, getPackageName(), sku, "inapp", "bGoa+V7g/yqDXvKRqq+JTFn4uQZbPiQJo4pf9RzJ");
PendingIntent pendingIntent = buyIntentBundle.getParcelable("BUY_INTENT");
startIntentSenderForResult(pendingIntent.getIntentSender(), 1001, new Intent(), Integer.valueOf(0), Integer.valueOf(0), Integer.valueOf(0));
```

This sends a response to the onActivityResult() method. According to the guidelines, the resultCode is either **Activity.RESULT_OK (1)** or **Activity.RESULT_CANCELED (0)**.

But looking into the Activity class, you find this:

```
 /** Standard activity result: operation canceled. */
public static final int RESULT_CANCELED    = 0;
/** Standard activity result: operation succeeded. */
public static final int RESULT_OK           = -1;
/** Start of user-defined activity results. */
public static final int RESULT_FIRST_USER   = 1;
```

And testing my application with a static inApp-purchase, i get the resultCode -1 if the purchase was successful.

So does the -1 and the 1 both indicate a successful purchase? And why is the Activity-class different from what is described in the guideline?

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of response codes. The Billing response codes (there are 8) includes the 0 for OK that you mention in the guidelines but this code is included in the bundle send back to the activity and is not the activity result code.  See http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_reference.html#getBuyIntent   Hope this helps

Comment: Was this answer any use to you Salatkopf?

Comment: I understand the difference between billing response codes(0-8) and result codes(-1,0,1). I also read the reference link you posted, which is exactly where i was quoting from in my original question! I'd like to know, when a **RESULT_FIRST_USER** is returned to onActivityResult()

Comment: Its explained here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32013948/will-someone-please-explain-result-first-user