# RESULT_OK, RESULT_CANCEL, RESULT_FIRST_USER definition or meaning

Tags: android

I am studying how to get a result form an activity and I am quite confused about the three terms.
I have read in Android documentation, but I feel it quite hard to understand for a beginner like me.

> RESULT_CANCELED: Standard activity result: operation canceled
>
> RESULT_OK: Standard activity result: operation succeeded

Please explain me what does it mean by operation here ?

> RESULT_FIRST_USER: Start of user-defined activity results

I tried to read [Will someone please explain RESULT_FIRST_USER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32013948/will-someone-please-explain-result-first-user)

but I still do not get the idea.

Comment: you read the comment of CommonsWare below the answer? it's explaining the point

Comment: I have read it. However, I am not an English native speaker, so I am not clear about the thing he said.

Answer (score 1):

The 'operation' is that what you start the new activity of which you want the result for.

For example if you start a camera activity to get some image from the camera with `startActivityForResult(cameraIntent)`. The operation is to get the image from the camera.

The RESULTs are to indicate to the caller what the result of the operation was, i.e. did it succeed or not.

Comment: Can you tell me what the use of it is ? I usually see it in `setResult(int requestCode, Intent intent)` method. But to my understanding, it can be any integers,do not need to be RESULT_OK

Comment: @LeQuynhAnh true, but these predefined codes are standard, mostly there is no need to use custom codes